# integral with incomplete upper gamma function

Tags: gamma-function

Can anyone help me evaluate the following integral:
$$
I(a)=\int_{a}^{\infty} e^{t}\, t^{-a}\, \Gamma(a-1,t)\, dt,
$$
where $a\in(0,1)$ is a fixed parameter and $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the upper incomplete Gamma function?

One idea is to use the integral representation
$$
e^{t} t^{-a}\Gamma(a-1,t)=\dfrac{1}{t}\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-ty}}{(1+y)^{2-a}}dy,
$$
which gives
$$
I(a)=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{E_{1}(ay)}{(1+y)^{2-a}}dy,
$$
where $E_1(z)$ denotes the basic exponential integral function. I am not sure how to proceed from here though.

Another idea is to use the integral representation
$$
e^{t} t^{-a}\Gamma(a-1,t)=\dfrac{1}{t\Gamma(2-a)}\int_0^{\infty}\dfrac{y^{1-a} e^{-y}}{(y+t)}dy,
$$
which gives
$$
I(a)=\dfrac{1}{\Gamma(2-a)}\int_0^\infty y^{-a} e^{-y}\log(1+y/a) dy;
$$
note that $a\in(0,1)$ so the integral is convergent.

Comment: That last integral diverges for $a \ge 2$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog: thanks, I edited the question to make it clear that $a\in(0,1)$ which is the case I am interested in. So the integral is convergent.

Comment: The previous comment had a truncated series. Here is a [better infinite series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gamma%28a-1%29-x%5E%28a-1%29%2F%28%28a-1%29e%5Ex%29+Sum%5B%28x%5Ek+Pochhammer%5B1%2C+k%5D%29%2F%28k%21+Pochhammer%5Ba%2C+k%5D%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+Infinity%7D%5D) to use.

Answer (score 1):

Using [**this series expansion**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gamma%28a-1%29-x%5E%28a-1%29%2F%28%28a-1%29e%5Ex%29+Sum%5B%28x%5Ek+Pochhammer%5B1%2C+k%5D%29%2F%28k%21+Pochhammer%5Ba%2C+k%5D%29%2C+%7Bk%2C+0%2C+Infinity%7D%5D) and the [Pocchhammer symbol $(u)_v$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pochhammer). We expand out the $k=0$ term of the sum to prevent $0$ division error:

$$\int e^t t^{-a}\left(\Gamma(a-1)-\frac{t^{a-1}}{(a-1)e^t}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{t^k}{(a)_k}\right)\right)dt=\int\Gamma(a-1)e^t t^{-a}dt-\int \frac{dt}{(a-1)t}-\int\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{t^{k-1}}{(a-1)(a)_k}dt$$

Now integrate and simplify the sum with the [$\,_2\text F_2$ hypergeometric function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddt+t+hypergeometricpfq%28%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B2%2Ca%2B1%7D%2Ct%29%2F%28%28a-1%29a%29) to get:

$$(-1)^a\Gamma(a-1)\Gamma(a-1,-t)-\frac{\ln(t)}{a-1}-\frac{t\,_2\text F_2(1,1;2,a+1;t)}{(a-1)a}$$

This answer will be polished later, but the general idea is there.